# Can Relativity be Proven Philosophically?

Tags: galilean-relativity

According to relativity, there is no preferred frame of reference. What I am wondering however, is if that could be proven philosophically. Is it logically impossible for a preferred frame of reference to exist? What would it mean for such a thing to be the case and "where" (if I can ask that) would this absolute frame of reference be? I feel like we can prove Galilean relativity just through the use of philosophy (not observation around us) but this is, of course, just a claim that I would love to get help or people to enjoy thinking about with me. I know we probably couldn't prove that everything has relative speeds except for the speed of light but that's more to do with Einsteinian relativity.

Comment: If you can prove Galilean relativity philosophically, then you are able to prove things that are false.

Comment: @G.Smith What do you mean? Galilean relativity is correct as far as I am aware. No?

Comment: No, it is incorrect. Perhaps you don’t understand what Galilean relativity means to physicists.

Comment: @G.Smith I know your opinion sir but I am asking for the actual reason you say this.

Comment: Galilean Relativity isn't incorrect. It is just limited. For everyday life, Galilean Relavity works very well. For a physicist workin at LCH, Galilean Relativity is useless.

Comment: Among *many* incorrect predictions of Galilean relativity is the prediction that a moving clock ticks at the same rate as a stationary clock.

Comment: @Thiago Thanks for the kind answer! I am aware it would have predicted that light has relative motion, so maybe that is what you meant be "limited"?

Comment: @G. Smith: physics is not mathematics. There is no "correct" theory in physics in the sense that you are claiming. Theories are adequate or not adequate to the situation you are working with. It is true that Special Relativity encapsulates Galilean Relativity and goes beyond, but this does not at all mean that Galileo was wrong.


@ Captain HD: you should have in mind what kind of "proof" you are talking about. "Proof" is physics is rather different than a mathematical/logical or philosophical proof.

Comment: Obligatory reminder that no claim about the physical world can be mathematically/logically proven, under any circumstances, ever.

Comment: @Thiago I am not stupid enough to claim that *any* physical theory is “correct”. But when a theory does not agree with experiment in some domain, it is incorrect in that domain. Galilean relativity is incorrect. Special relativity is incorrect. General relativity is likely to be incorrect.

Comment: @G.Smith I guess it is a bit of a personal preference to say what idea is wrong and what is right. For example, are real-valued solutions wrong just because they are not the most general solutions since we could also have had a complex solution in a certain problem? Galilean relativity might not have told us the right physics when applied to a certain situation but if you want to call it wrong in that scenario when what was actually wrong here was the application of it, then sure... It is wrong!

Comment: @J.Murray It might be able to. A possible example could be Zeno's paradox which has proposed solutions, but remains unsolved as of today. If it could be solved then it might give physical insight to things. This is not a proposed solution but let's say the solution turned out to be something like a discrete universe in terms of space and time. If you could get such cool information from a philosophical paradox then that would be awesome!

Comment: @G. Smith. I did not say you are stupid. But it is not correct to say that the ticking of clocks predicted by galilean relativity is incorrect. It is pretty much "correct" for small velocities.

Comment: @Thiago You have an extremely bizarre notion that “correct” and “does not agree with experiment” are compatible. A clock on something moving as slowly as an airplane ticks at a *measurably different* rate. You know this. Feel free to have the last word because I am not going to continue this conversation.

Comment: @CaptainHD *I guess it is a bit of a personal preference to say what idea is wrong and what is right.* There are theories that agree with experiment and theories that don’t. Personal preference only comes into play when multiple theories are able to predict exactly what is observed, within experimental error. Physicists then tend to choose the simpler one.

Comment: @G. Smith: you wrote above that Galilean Relativity "is incorrect" (your words). All I'm friendly trying to say is that "incorrect" is not a good word. When you do an experiment (say, of a clock in an airplane) you are reaching the limits of validity of Galileo's claim. So Galilean Relativity is not incorrect, it is just limited. Indeed it was correct for centuries. If Galilean Relativity was incorrect in the logical/mathematical sense, then 
SR and GR would also be incorrect, since they contain Galilean Relativity in them. I'm friendly trying to tell that. Best wishes.

Comment: This reminds me of a quote that was on the wall of an insurance loss modelling company I interned at: "essentially all models are wrong, but some models are useful". Physics is all about fitting models to describe reality and proposing new models whenever a breaking point is found.

Comment: Kant had the concept of [a priori knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori). It works ok for mathematics, but not for empirical stuff like physics. Kant thought that a priori knowledge lets us know that space has 3 dimensions, but that's faulty thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Galilean and Special Relativity do not state that there are no preferred frames, they postulate it, and see what are the physical/astronomical consequences of this postulate.

It is not logically impossible to have a preferred frame. In fact, CMB does introduce a privileged frame: the one where the CMB has no dipole. You can also say that the expansion of the universe defines a privileged time and frame -- the ones used by freely falling galaxies. Bottom line: privileged frames exist and are everywhere in nature.

If you feel you can prove Galilean Relativity with no observation, then by definition this is not the kind of scientific proof that physicists usually work with, since a scientific proof is one guided by observation/experiments.

I think you should post your question in a Philosophy forum.

Comment: Hey again, maybe I'm breaking a rule slightly, but I think I can stretch this a little. I just have a quick side question, and that is what frame of reference we are using when we say the Sun is orbiting around a centre of mass which is almost aligned along it's own axis. Is it the background of all the fixed stars? If so then what is meant by "background of fixed stars" exactly and how would it tie in with relativity?

Comment: @CaptainHD We often use a frame where the Sun is fixed. But it can be more useful to work in a frame where the Sun orbits the [solar system barycentre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter#Inside_or_outside_the_Sun?). As you can see, it's not a simple orbit. There are no "fixed stars": everything's moving, but on short time scales we can ignore that motion, especially of the more distant stars in our galaxy. On longer timescales, most visible stars move a fair bit, and the modern sky is rather different to what it was when dinosaurs were dominant.